# Watering flowers or vegetable on Chol Hamoed

Tags: money, melacha-creative-work, agriculture, chol-hamoed, modern-times

The first mishna in Moed Katan delineates limitations on agricultural work that may be performed on the less sanctified intermediate days of a festival (*chol hamoed*).  The Shulchan Aruch (OC 537) codifies these limitations based on the principle of substantial loss (*davar ha'aved*), whereby which, if a field would be ruined if not watered, minor efforts are allowed to save it.  How does this translate to modern applications of leisure gardening - e.g. of decorative flower beds or vegetable gardens that are grown for decoration or as a hobby, but not out of a financial need? If seeds planted before the festival would die if left unwatered, is that considered a *davar ha'aved*, even though there is no significant economic impact?  Where is the *halachic* line drawn?

(These sites *sound* like they are lenient, but they do not appear to provide explicit sources or reasoning:

- https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/sat_10_26_13/
- http://helpfulhalacha.blogspot.com/2010/04/laws-of-chol-hamoed-intermediate.html